# Spring MVC success, but page isn't refreshed, returns blank page

Tags: spring-mvc

When I loaded at first run project, thanhviens.jsp will be loaded. But I add a new user, it return to thanhviens.jsp and doesn't have any data to display. It's a blank page. When I go back to index and click to /listUser, the page loads with the data I saved before that.

This is my code for the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/account")
public class ThanhVienController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/ListUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllUser(ModelMap mm)
{
    try {
        List<Thanhvien> lst = ThanhVienDAO.layDS();
        mm.addAttribute("listUser", lst);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "thanhviens";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addUser(ModelMap mm)
{
    mm.put("u", new Thanhvien());
    return "add";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "u")Thanhvien user, ModelMap mm)
{
    Integer check = null;
    check = ThanhVienDAO.addUser(user);
    if (check!=null) {
        return "thanhviens";
    }
    else
    {
        mm.put("errMess", "Error!!");
        return "add";
    } 
}
}
```

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure that your verb tenses match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you add user you are not setting the listUser model attribute. That's why it is not showing anything. below code should work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "u")Thanhvien user, ModelMap mm)
{
    Integer check = null;
    check = ThanhVienDAO.addUser(user);
    if (check!=null) {
        List<Thanhvien> lst = ThanhVienDAO.layDS();
        lst.add(user);//new user
        mm.addAttribute("listUser", lst);
        return "thanhviens";
    }
    else
    {
        mm.put("errMess", "Error!!");
        return "add";
    } 
}
```